# Contar nº de ocorrências num for in loop {Bash}

Tags: linux, shell, bash, terminal, for

Eu tenho o seguinte script

```
    #!/bin/bash
for file in *.jpg;
do
        convert $file -resize 1920x1080! -blur 0x8 alterado$file;
        echo "A Processar o ficheiro $file"
done
```

Eu quero fazer um echo com

> A processador o ficheiro xpto ( 1 de 100)

Como eu consigo obter o index e numero total de ocorrências?
Eu podia fazer outro script para listar os ficheiros do directório e contar o resultado, mas gostava de saber como posso fazer isso com o loop for ... in

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você pode fazer isso:

```
#!/bin/bash

total=$(ls -l *.jpg | wc -l);
contador=1;

for file in *.jpg;
do
        echo "A Processar o ficheiro $file ($contador de $total)";
        convert $file -resize 1920x1080! -blur 0x8 alterado$file;            
        contador=$((contador+1));
done
```

Explicação:

A variável total é obtida por meio da execução de um comando que conta quantos arquivos do tipo *.jpg estão no diretório corrente.

Já a variável contador é utilizada para mostrar o progresso. A mesma é incrementada a cada final do loop.

Comment: @lazyFox, não entendi muito bem o que você deseja. Poderia esclarecer melhor?